# how to handle outgoing-webhook (Slack) using php

Tags: php, html, webhooks, slack

i have configured Slack outgoing-webhook, but i'm not sure how to handle HTTP POST request which was send by Slack to my specified URL.
Workflow is like this. when someone sends a message to specified channel, then an HTTP POST request will be sent by API to one of the specified URL (on which i can do something with that POST).
Currently i'm not able to handle that request in my PHP code.
i used below code, as it works for POSTs made by forms.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text'])){ echo $_POST['text'];}
?>
```

but it does'nt work. As i'm receiving POST from API, i need to handle this request to get data from it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your script is reachable with a public URL and correctly configured in Slack as [outgoing webhook](https://api.slack.com/outgoing-webhooks) (remember you need either a trigger word or configure a public channel) it will receive the Slack request. The Slack parameters can be accessed as you did through the superglobal `$_POST`, however your echo command will not work.

If you want to send a message back to Slack your need to use the Slack format for messages. Here is an example:

```
$message = ["text" => "Hello Slack"];
echo json_encode($message);
```

But be careful. If you have configured the webhook to listen for a channel sending back a message to Slack will again trigger the webhook and create a loop. So only do that if you have configured the webhook to listen to trigger words.

Or if you just want to see want has been received, I would recommend to write it into a log, so that you can review it later. Here is a very simple and easy to use [Logger](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/Logger) for PHP. Its nothing fancy, but works nicely for small projects and tests. Or use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), a popular Logger for PHP.